# Icons in the top right menu - what's the meaning?

Tags: 18.04, menu, ux

[image]

Hi, can anyone tell me what is the UX supposed to be for ubuntu Menu? How am I supposed to know what the buttons do? There is no "hover over it" to know. 
In my case I am trying to find out what does the second button from the left do, because "Super" key stopped working and I read somewhere that it's possible to lock it (whaat?).

Comment: What documentation have you looked at?   The standard desktop for Ubuntu 18.04 is GNOME, so GNOME documentation is useful, let alone Ubuntu documentation.  For example https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/ might be a good start (that's the stable or latest version, ie. 19.10, most will apply perfectly to 18.04)

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-exit.html.en  - doesn't say anything about the icon I have

Comment: or this one: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-introduction.html.en#systemmenu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rotation Lock (2nd icon from the left in the screenshot from GNOME desktop environment) toggles the screen to/from portrait mode ⟷ landscape mode.

The four icons from left to right are as follows:

- Settings
- Rotation Lock
- Lock Screen
- Power Off ⏻